# I can't make an Insert in MYSQL with a SOAP web service in Java using JDBC driver

Tags: java, mysql, web-services, soap, netbeans-8

Hi im trying to test a web service Soap java which is connected to mysql localhost (xampp) but i can't insert any row in the data base
Here is my code

Conexion.java

```
import java.sql.Connection
import java.sql.DriverManager

public class Conexion {

public static final Connection ConectarMySQL() throws SQLException
{
    Connection conn;
    try
    {          
        conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/controldecalidad", "root", "");            
    }
    catch(SQLException ex)
    {
        throw new SQLException(ex.getMessage());
    }
    return conn;
}
```

}

and here is the webservice

```
 @WebMethod(operationName= "registra_rechazo")   
public void registra_rechazo(@WebParam(name = "SKU")String SKU,@WebParam(name = "fecha")String fecha,
        @WebParam(name = "num_captura")String num_captura,@WebParam(name = "pesoCaptura") int pesoCaptura) 
{
    try
    {
        Connection conn = Conexion.ConectarMySQL();
        String sql = "INSERT INTO registra_rechazo VALUES(?,?,?,?)";
        PreparedStatement pst = conn.prepareStatement(sql);
        pst.setString(1, SKU);   
        SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-mm-dd");            
        pst.setString(2, dateFormat.format(fecha));
        pst.setString(3, num_captura);
        pst.setInt(4, pesoCaptura);
        pst.execute();
        pst.close();
        conn.close();

    }
    catch(SQLException Ex)
    {

    } 
}
```

and here is the error
https://i.stack.imgur.com/aWO16.png

**UPDATE!!** i checked my proyect and i got this new error
https://i.stack.imgur.com/uHRQW.png

what im missing? please help!!!!

Comment: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException is thrown when the method you invoked tries to invoke another method that throws an exception, so my advice would be to check the log and try to follow the stack trace to see where the error originally came from

Comment: Hi! thank you for you feedback y re-checked the conexion class and i try it in other proyect and was correct with no errors so de Connection instance is not the problem, then i change prepared statement to stament and i had a java.lang.NullPointerException error :/

Comment: in the update, is that the complete error message? If it's not post the whole error, I believe it should list what causes it exactly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**I FINALLY SOLVED IT !!**

in the class Conexion y remove the static final and i create a constructor for this class

```
public class Conexion {

public Conexion(){

}    
public Connection getConecction()
{
    Connection con = null;
    try{
        Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
        con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/controldecalidad", "root", "");                        
    }catch(SQLException ex){            
    }
    catch(Exception ex){
    }
    return con;
    }    
}
```

then i created a class who have all the operations

```
public class Operaciones 
{
   Conexion conexion;

public Operaciones()
{
    conexion = new Conexion();
}


public boolean registra_rechazo(String SKU,String fecha,String num_captura,int pesoCaptura)
{
    Boolean bandera=false;
     try
    {
        Connection conn = conexion.getConecction();
        java.util.Date utilStartDate = new java.util.Date(fecha);
        java.sql.Date sqlStartDate = new java.sql.Date(utilStartDate.getTime());           
        String sql = "INSERT INTO registra_rechazo VALUES(?,?,?,?)";
        PreparedStatement pst = conn.prepareStatement(sql);
        pst.setString(1, SKU);   
        pst.setDate(2, sqlStartDate);
        pst.setString(3, num_captura);
        pst.setInt(4, pesoCaptura);
        if(pst.executeUpdate()!=-1){
            bandera = true;
            return bandera;
        }
        else{
            bandera = false;
            return bandera;

        }

    }
    catch(SQLException Ex)
    {

    }
     return bandera;
   }
}
```

then i call the method in the web service, but first the web method must be created by add operation in the web service like the image

https://i.stack.imgur.com/HjAHk.png

i dont know why but the method only works if you created the method with that wizard

```
@WebMethod(operationName = "operation")
public boolean operation(@WebParam(name = "SKU") String SKU, @WebParam(name = "fecha") String fecha, @WebParam(name = "num_captura") String num_captura, @WebParam(name = "peso_captura") int peso_captura) {
    //TODO write your implementation code here:
     Operaciones op = new Operaciones();
    return op.registra_rechazo(SKU,fecha,num_captura,peso_captura);
}
```

and then the web method must return something, with void will not work